# Triple-nested form with Rails form_with and strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, nested-forms, strong-parameters

I'm running Rails 6.0.0.rc1 and having trouble getting a triple nested form working. I have `products` that have `options` that have `option_values`. So a Product might have an option called "Color" and an Option Value named "Red." I'd like to create all of these in a [classic nested form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised?autoplay=true) in the Product form.

The form works and I can save Product with an Option, but not the Option Value on submit. I'm not sure why it's not working when I try to embed `fields_for` Option Values inside the `fields_for` Options.

What am I doing wrong here? I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but can't figure it out. (Probably not relevant, but note that I need to scope each object to `account_id` and my User `has_one :account` that's the reason for the hidden field.)

Here is my product model:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account

  has_many :options, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :options, allow_destroy: true

  validates :account_id,  presence: true
  validates :name,        presence: true
end
```

Option model:

```
class Option < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :product

  has_many :option_values, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :option_values, allow_destroy: true

  validates :account_id,  presence: true
  validates :name,        presence: true
end
```

OptionValue model:

```
class OptionValue < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :option

  validates :account_id,  presence: true
  validates :name,        presence: true
end
```

Here's the Product form:

```
<%= form_with(model: product, local: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :options do |options_form| %>
    <fieldset class='form-group'>
      <%= options_form.hidden_field :account_id, value: current_user.account.id %>
      <%= options_form.label :name, 'Option' %>
      <%= options_form.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
    </fieldset>

    <%= f.fields_for :option_values do |values_form| %>
      <fieldset class='form-group'>
        <%= values_form.label :name, 'Value' %>
        <%= values_form.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
      </fieldset>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

ProductsController:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @product = Product.new
    @product.options.build
  end

  def create
    @account = current_user.account
    @product = @account.products.build(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

  private 
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(
        :account_id, :name,
        options_attributes: [
          :id, :account_id, :name, :_destroy,
          option_values_attributes:[:id, :account_id, :name, :_destroy ]
        ]
      )
    end
end
```

Comment: In the form `f.fields_for :option_values` are nested inside the main form, but should be nested inside `options_form`

Comment: Thanks, but isn't `f.fields_for :option_values` nested inside `f.fields_for :options` ?

Comment: It is nested in terms of html markup, but not in terms of rails form_helper. Should be `options_form.fields_for :option_values`

Comment: Also, you don't have account_id field for option_values in the form, but this attribute is validated.

Comment: ok, that makes sense, but when I add `<%= options_form.fields_for :option_values do |values_form| %>` It doesn't render the `values_form` fields in the browser.

Comment: Yes, because you need to create some options and values before rendering. Or you can use [cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) to handle it with JS

Comment: I was trying to do this in the classic rails cast way (similar to how Ryan Bates did this with Survey > Question > Answer) before moving on to adding javascript. In the railscast Ryan had the form with two nested layers working at this point without JS, and the only thing that I can tell that's changed about rails since then is Strong Parameters, so I was trying to get it working without JS or a gem first so that I understand how Rails handles this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194209/discussion-between-vasilisa-and-lee-mcalilly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, you need to change the form to nest `option_values` inside `option`, and add `account_id` field to option values:

```
<%= form_with(model: product, local: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :options do |options_form| %>
    <fieldset class='form-group'>
      <%= options_form.hidden_field :account_id, value: current_user.account.id %>
      <%= options_form.label :name, 'Option' %>
      <%= options_form.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
    </fieldset>

    <%= options_form.fields_for :option_values do |values_form| %>
      <fieldset class='form-group'>
        <%= values_form.hidden_field :account_id, value: current_user.account.id %>
        <%= values_form.label :name, 'Value' %>
        <%= values_form.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
      </fieldset>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Also you need to build nested records in the controller. Another option is to build them dynamically via javascript (look at the [cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon), for example). To build 3 options with 3 values each:

```
def new 
  @account = current_user.account 
  # it is better to create associated product 
  @product = @account.products.new 
  3.times do 
    option = @product.options.build 
    3.times { option.option_values.build } 
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Because I was trying to follow along [this Nested Form Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised), the biggest problem was that I didn't realize that the version Ryan Bates has working is on "Edit", not "New", so I added the Products, Options, and Values via the console and got the form working with this code:

_form.html.erb

```
  <%= f.fields_for :options do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'option_fields', f: builder %>
  <% end %>
```

_option_fields.html.erb

```
<fieldset class='form-group'>
  <%= f.hidden_field :account_id, value: current_user.account.id %>

  <%= f.label :name, 'Option' %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
  <br>
  <%= f.check_box :_destroy, class: 'form-check-input' %>
  <%= f.label :_destroy, 'Remove Option' %>

  <small id="optionHelp" class="form-text text-muted">
    (e.g. "Size" or "Color")
  </small>

  <%= f.fields_for :option_values do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'option_value_fields', f: builder %>
  <% end %>

</fieldset>
```

_option_value_fields.html.erb

```
<fieldset class='form-group'>
  <%= f.hidden_field :account_id, value: current_user.account.id %>
  <%= f.label :name, 'Value' %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
  <br>
  <%= f.check_box :_destroy, class: 'form-check-input' %>
  <%= f.label :_destroy, 'Remove Value' %>

  <small id="optionValueHelp" class="form-text text-muted">
    (e.g. "Small, Medium, Large" or "Red, Green, Blue")
  </small>
</fieldset>
```

Also, the only difference with the Railscast is using strong parameters in the controller, so you'll just need to nest them like this:

ProductsController

```
def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:account_id, :name, options_attributes [:id, :account_id, :name, :_destroy, option_values_attributes: [:id, :account_id, :name, :_destroy]])
end
```

OptionsController

```
def option_params
     params.require(:option).permit(:account_id, :name, option_values_attributes [:id, :account_id, :name, :_destroy])
end
```

OptionValuesController

```
def option_value_params
     params.require(:option_value).permit(:account_id, :option_id, :name)
end
```

Rather than building the nested objects in the controller I'm going to do it with Javascript as in the Railscast episode or with the [Cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) as [Vasilisa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9269043/vasilisa) suggested in her answer.

Just wanted to share the code that actually ended up working in case someone else runs into similar problems. I think the Railscast, though old, is still a great introduction to nested forms in Rails, but you just have to be aware of the changes required to use form_with and strong parameters. Big thanks to [Vasilisa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9269043/vasilisa) for helping me figure this out.

The main "gotchas" that you need to look out for when following the [Rails Nested Form Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised?autoplay=true) are this:

- form_with has some different syntax than the older rails form_tag
- Make sure you don't have any typos or name problems when creating your form blocks because these are nested twice
- Same with nesting parameters in your controllers, just be aware of your syntax and typos
- Be aware that Ryan Bates is demoing with data that wasn't added through the form he's building so if you'd like to follow along you'll need to create some data in the console
- With strong parameters you'll have to explicitly list `:_destroy` as a parameter in order for his "Remove" checkboxes to work